# В input на Iphone не виден текст

Tags: css3, safari

Не отображается текст при вводе в input на iphone. При этом курсор двигается
http://prntscr.com/ojyx7r
Сайт: https://www.tuk33.ru/
Например, если нажати на ссылку в шапке "Не дозвонились" выйдет форма. И с ней при заполнении не видно текст.

Comment: Добавьте line-height: 1; - это должно помочь.